# Конкатенация широких строк (WideString)

Tags: c, winapi

Не нашёл функций конкатенаций типов `wchar_t` или `WCHAR`(псевдноним `wchar_t` в WinAPI). Есть ли такая функция?

Comment: Так а что такое "конкатенация"? А для обычных строк есть такая функция?

Comment: wcscat, скрепление двух строк.
Или strcat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, конечно - все аналоги для широких строк имеются.

Для `strcat` это [`wcscat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcscat).

Ориентируйтесь на замену части `str...` на `wcs...` - типа, аналог `strlen` - `wcslen` и т.д.

Comment: Точнее подошло wcscat:) Большое спасибо.